# How to get cassandra meta data?

Tags: cassandra

I'm in making a gui client for Cassandra.

How to get details of existing key-spaces, column family, column details in Cassandra?

Is there any meta data storing tables in cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the metadata about Cassandra is in the system keyspace.

A better solution might be to use the DataStax JavaDriver to connect to the Cluster, then use the MetaData available there so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster c = com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoint(cluster.getContactPoint()).withPort(cluster.getRpcPort()).build();

c.connect();
Metadata md = c.getMetadata();
List<KeyspaceMetadata> keyspaces = md.getKeyspaces();
c.close();
```

There are other methods on the Metadata object to get just about anything you need from the cluster configuration.